# Access MongoDB Atlas from AWS EMR 6.1.0/6.2.0 with Spark 3.x

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr, mongodb-atlas

The issue arises when we tried to update from `AWS EMR 5.30.1` to `AWS EMR 6.1.0` (Same error for `6.2.0` too).

The AWS EMR 6.1.x+ is using Spark 3.x. So we've changed the jar to access MongoDB from `org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.2` to `org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.0`. When trying to connect to the mongo uri, we got the following:

```
20/12/15 07:12:22 INFO cluster: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017], srvHost=mysite.a0lo8.mongodb.net, mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=REPLICA_SET, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', requiredReplicaSetName='atlas-qd6vi5-shard-0'}
20/12/15 07:12:22 INFO MongoClientCache: Creating MongoClient: []
20/12/15 07:12:22 INFO cluster: Adding discovered server mysite-shard-00-02.a0lo8.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
20/12/15 07:12:22 INFO cluster: Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
20/12/15 07:12:22 INFO cluster: Adding discovered server mysite-shard-00-01.a0lo8.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
20/12/15 07:12:22 INFO cluster: Adding discovered server mysite-shard-00-00.a0lo8.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
20/12/15 07:12:22 INFO cluster: No server chosen by com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@6ea6f35 from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=REPLICA_SET, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=mysite-shard-00-00.a0lo8.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, ServerDescription{address=mysite-shard-00-02.a0lo8.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, ServerDescription{address=mysite-shard-00-01.a0lo8.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
20/12/15 07:12:25 INFO cluster: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server mysite-shard-00-01.a0lo8.mongodb.net:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:127)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:284)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:63)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65)
    ... 3 more
20/12/15 07:12:25 INFO cluster: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server mysite-shard-00-02.a0lo8.mongodb.net:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:127)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:284)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:63)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65)
    ... 3 more
20/12/15 07:12:25 INFO cluster: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server mysite-shard-00-00.a0lo8.mongodb.net:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:127)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:284)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:63)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65)
    ... 3 more
20/12/15 07:12:52 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User application exited with status 1
20/12/15 07:12:52 INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 1, (reason: User application exited with status 1)
20/12/15 07:12:52 INFO MongoClientCache: Closing MongoClient: [mysite-shard-00-00.a0lo8.mongodb.net:27017,mysite-shard-00-02.a0lo8.mongodb.net:27017,mysite-shard-00-01.a0lo8.mongodb.net:27017]
20/12/15 07:12:52 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
20/12/15 07:12:52 INFO AbstractConnector: Stopped Spark@2d0dfe0{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:0}
```

We are using the mongo srv uri like this: `mongodb+srv://user:pass@mysite.a0lo8.mongodb.net`. It seems impossible to access to MongoDB Atlas. Reverting to `AWS EMR 5.30.1`, `Spark 2.4.5` and the jar for Spark MongoDB  `org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.2` with the same uri is working. But then, we can't use Spark 3.x which defeated the purpose.

Has anyone successfully connected a AWS EMR 6.1.x+ (with a Spark 3.x) to MongoDB Atlas ?

I think the issue is with AWS EMR 6.1+ because launching the spark application from localhost and then writing to mongodb atlas is working as well.

Answer (score 1):

We had the exact same issue. So far, the only solution we've found is to revert back to AWS EMR `5.30.1` and the corresponding mongo connector jar: `2.11:2.4.2`. As the OP said, it seems to be related to EMR, as we were also able to connect to Mongo Atlas from localhost without a problem.

Comment: We've moved to AWS EMR 5.32.0 and 5.33.0 successfully too. But it's still KO with the latest version AWS EMR 6.3.0 with Spark 3.1.1 now. It seems there's something wrong going on with EMR 6.1.x+ with mongo atlas URI. Did you manage to find a solution since ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by Docker, its CIDR collides with Mongo Atlas CIDR. [EMR 6.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-600-release.html) runs Hadoop 3.2.1 and Docker was introduced in [Hadoop 3.1.1](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/DockerContainers.html) while [EMR 5.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-app-versions-5.x.html) runs Hadoop 2.10.1.

Two possible solutions:

- Change CIDR in Mongo Atlas
- Disable Docker in EMR cluster

The following script disables Docker and can be used to bootstrap an EMR cluster. The disabling is conducted once the node provision is completed, thus `disable_docker()` must be run in the background.

```
#!/bin/bash

disable_docker(){
    sec=10

    while true;
    do
        node_provision_state=$(sed -n '/localInstance [{]/,/[}]/{
            /nodeProvisionCheckinRecord [{]/,/[}]/ {
            /status: / { p }
            /[}]/a
            }
            /[}]/a
            }' /emr/instance-controller/lib/info/job-flow-state.txt | awk ' { print $2 }'
        )

        if [ "$node_provision_state" == "SUCCESSFUL" ];
        then
            sleep $sec;
            echo "attempting to disable docker"

            # disable network
            sudo ifconfig docker0 down
            br_net=$(ifconfig | grep "^br*" | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d : -f1)
            sudo ifconfig "$br_net" down

            echo "successfully disabled docker"
            exit;
        else
            echo "node provision not completed yet, sleeping ${sec} seconds.."
        fi

        sleep $sec;
    done
}

# run in background
disable_docker &
echo "running disable docker function in the background"
```